# Designing a Power Series with certain $R$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Out of interest, is there a way to design a series with a certain radius of convergence? For example, $R=8$, or is there a way to turn a series for which the Radius of Convergence is known, then manipulating it to get a new radius of convergence?

Answer (score 2):

If $0<R<\infty$, then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}R^{-n}x^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, because for fixed $x$ it is just a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is:

If $$ \sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}c_n(z-a)^n$$ is a power series with radius of convergence R, then for any $\lambda > 0$ the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}c_n\left(\frac{z-a}{\lambda}\right)^n$$
converges iff $\left\lvert\frac{z-a}{\lambda}\right\rvert < R$, i.e., iff $|z-a| < \lambda R$.

Hence, the power series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\frac{c_n}{\lambda^n}\left(z-a\right)^n$$
has radius of convergence $\lambda R$.